# Loop through a file and sed substitute each line

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, sed

I have the following bash script:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
      line=$(echo $line | sed "s/\'/\'\'/")

      [[ $line =~ ^\<ID\>(.*) ]] && printf "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done <  <(dos2unix < file)
```

EDITED version of script without dos2unix:

```
while IFS= read -r line && line=${line%$'\r'}; do
   [[ $line =~ ^\<ID\>(.*) ]] && printf "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```

I want to substitute every apostrophe in "file" with 2 apostrophes **BEFORE** I loop through it. How can I do this? I'd be grateful for any suggestions concerning any of the 2 versions.
**IMPORTANT** 
Im **NOT** allowed to modify the original file!!

Comment: You have `<ID>` in there. Is this XML? If so, then it'd be a really good idea to use an XML parser.

Comment: @Sobrique Im extracting data from text files to create a sql file and then I do .read file.sql to create and load the database

Comment: What exactly does “doesn't work properly” mean?

Comment: Can you give some example data? I'd probably tackle this in perl myself.

Comment: `Loop through a file and sed substitute each line` = `Can I have "Things I should never do" for 100 please Alex?`. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do whatever you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: @EdMorton I made a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385844/improving-a-slow-inefficient-bash-script-for-extracting-data-from-files

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `sed` alone:

```
sed 's/\r$//;s/\'/\'\'/g;s/^<ID>\(.*\)/\1/p;d' < file
```

The steps are:

1. `sed` accepts multiple commands separated with newlines, semicolons or given as multiple `-e` options.
2. `sed 's/\r$//;` removes the CR at end of each line like `dos2unix`.
3. The `g` flag added to `s/\'/\'\'/` means replace *all* occurrences in the line; default is to replace just one.
4. The `s/^<ID>\(.*\)/\1/` does the equivalent of that bash regex match and the `p` flag at the end makes sed print the matching lines *now*, because
5. The `d` command removes the line so it won't get printed by default (you could do that with the `-n` option instead).

On a side-note, my zsh does not accept `\'` in `'`, so I'd probably write it

```
sed -n -e 's/\r$//' -e "s/'/''/g" -e 's/^<ID>\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

It should be equivalent, just switching the quote style, separate options and the `-n` instead of final `d`.

Comment: Commands like these illustrate why the power of a tool like `sed` is limited by the ability of human brains to decipher its "efficient" syntax as soon as the instructions are no longer trivial.

Comment: This is not a criticism of `sed` or your proposed solution, by the way, just an observation that there clearly is a trade-off in readability and maintainability required to achieve the "magic one-liner that does everything".

Comment: @Fred, those were the days of 4800-baud teletype terminals where every keystroke incurred visible delay so everybody wanted to type as little as possible.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes for the possibilities of sed, I never knew you could do that. However, my script is kind of long and I would rather not change it completely. I tried substituting done <  <(dos2u nix < file) with done < "$currentFile" | sed "s/\r$//;s/\'/\'\'/g" but now the script doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: `"$currentFile" | sed` is trying to _execute_ "$currentFile". You need to say `<(sed … < "$currentFile")`

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a "solution" (your question is not clear on what is not working in your code), you certainly should avoid calling `sed` for each individual line.  It is not "wrong" in the sense of producing an incorrect result, but it is so much slower that it should be avoided.  There are ways do it that are both faster and simpler to code.

Do it this way :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
      [[ $line =~ ^\<ID\>(.*) ]] && printf "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done <  <(dos2unix < file | sed "s/\'/\'\'/")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do but when I add the sed part, the script doesn't do anything